# Exporting a single Google contact as a vcard

Tags: google-contacts, export

In Google Contacts, I can't find a way to export a single contact as a vcard. I've tried to do it from the Gmail contacts view and from [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com).

Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

**Update:** I realize I could make a one person group and export that. I'd prefer a workflow that didn't reek of workaround..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** I am updating this answer because as of 18 Jan 2012 Google has just announced that:

> The standalone Contacts service now has the same interface and
>   features that are currently available in Contacts inside of Gmail.

<strike>Make sure you use the contacts view available from GMail and NOT the one at contacts.google.com which has not been updated by Google in a very long time.</strike>

The rest of these instructions are still correct:

1. in Gmail contacts view select the entry you want
2. Click on "More actions" and then "Export..."
3. Leave the default for "Which contacts do you want to export?" as "Selected contacts (1)"
4. Change "Which export format?" to "vCard format"

Comment: So you have to do it from the gmail contacts view as opposed to contacts.google.com. That seems rather annoying and unituitive.

Comment: Yes, you must use the gmail contacts view and NOT contacts.google.com which has languished in comparison. They need to replace the old interface with a redirect to gmail contacts. They've been killing off things like Wave and Buzz, so maybe this old interface will finally get the axe soon, too!

Comment: @JustinDearing I updated my answer because Google just announced they have finally made the interface at [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com) the same as the GMail contacts interface.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Gmail contacts view, create a new group and name it as "Temp".
2. Put the contact you want to export as vcard to "Temp" group. (mark the contact, click on Groups, select Temp)
3. Click on "More actions" and then "Export...".
4. Now select "Temp" group together with the export format you like, click on "Export", and you're done.

Comment: If thats the only what then thats a major UX problem on gmail's part. I'll mark this as correct if no one offers a better alternative.