# Attach a vCard of a Google contact in an email

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

This is related to [Exporting a single Google contact as a vCard](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8116/exporting-a-single-google-contact-as-a-vcard) in that it would remove a step from the most common case use of that question.

Lets say I have two friends, Alice and Bob. Lets say Alice would like Bobs email address. I would like to be able to go into Google contacts, find Bobs contact info, and be able to email it to Alice. Does Gmail/Google contacts allow you to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not easily. You can only export all your contacts or those in a particular group. So you'd need to put the person you want to export into a group by themselves to export their data.

Rather an oversight, I think. You'll probably need to resort to a third-party tool, if one exists.

For what it's worth, this is really easy with Android.

Updated: You can [export a selected contact to an individual VCard](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8116/exporting-a-single-google-contact-as-a-vcard), then attach in an email.

Comment: not only Android but every mobile device ... but, incredible hard using the simply computer browser :-/ What were they thinking?

Comment: I can't find a way to do this in Android contacts, version 6.0.  It says it can do it (go to contact, select "share" from menu, send an email), but no contact info is actually added or attached to the email.  WTF?

Comment: @nealmcb: I don't know what to tell you. I just tested it with my phone and a `vcf` file was attached to the file. Maybe your OEM has monkeyed with the Contacts app. (FWIW mine's at v. 5.1-7.) You might ask about the issue you're having at [android.se].

Comment: Thanks - shall do, though I'm on a Nexus 6.  But already there I found the complementary problem, reported as an issue that at first glance seems to be ignored: by default Android won't import vcf files from an sms: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2412

Comment: The question is about exporting, not importing.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually export a single contact to a csv file, attach the downloaded file to the email (easy with Google Chrome), and send the email with attachment to the recipient. The only thing is they have to download the attachment and import it from Google Contacts. Google Contacts does a good job of importing, but you still have to dig through your files and find the downloads folder and the file. You'd think there would be an easier way, but it IS possible to send a single contact.